# How make a comma separated string into a separted value in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

My HTMl:

```
<div class="jobDiv" data-dir-paginate="item in data.allJobs|filter:categoryFilterFn|orderBy:'item.PublishDate':true| itemsPerPage:10">
    <h3>
        <a href="{{item.JobID}}">{{item.JobTitle}}</a>
        <span class="pull-right label label-primary" style="margin-top:20px;">
            <b>Budget:</b>  {{item.Budget | currency}}
        </span>
    </h3>
    <b>Deadline: </b><span>{{item.Deadline|date:'mediumDate'}}</span><br /><br />
    <div class="lead">{{item.JobDetails|cut:true:125}}</div>

    @*<b>Skills: </b> <label class="label label-default" style="margin-right:3px; padding:3px 10px;" ng-repeat="ss in item.SkillNames">{{ss.SkillNames}}</label>*@
    Skills: <label class="label label-success" style="background-color:blue; padding:10px 18px;">{{item.SkillNames}}</label>
</div>
```

Now for item.SkillNames i get value just like: **PHP,ASP,Java**
How can make it like PHP   ASP Java
I tried this bur not working:

```
 <b>Skills: </b> <label class="label label-default" style="margin-right:3px; padding:3px 10px;" ng-repeat="ss in item.SkillNames">{{ss.SkillNames}}</label>
```

I want to get like:
[image]

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Comment: The best & more readable solution is to return an array of skill names instead of a comma separated list from your server

Comment: Shouldn't have taken a whole lot of research to figure this out

Answer (score 3):

The best and more readable solution is to return an array of skill names instead of a comma separated list from your server. You can use this array with `ng-repeat`.

If you cannot do that and want to still make it work with your current data structure, you can call [string.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method on your single string which has comma separated list of skill names. The split method returns an array and you can use this array with `ng-repeat`

Like this

```
<span style="background-color:gray; padding: 4px; margin-right: 4px;"
                 ng-repeat="skillName in item.SkillNames.split(',')">{{skillName}}</span>
```

You may also consider moving your inline css to a css class and use that for easy maintenance and re usability(as needed)